# Was Yaakov lacking Bitachon?

Tags: sin, avot-patriarch-fathers, reward-punishment, faith-bitachon-emunah, zechut-merit

When Yaakov becomes afraid of Eisav's arrival, the *passuk* says that he was very frightened. Chazal in Maseches Brachos note that he was afraid שמא יגרום החטא. Does this display a lack of Bitachon, especially since Hashem promised Yaakov that he will be taken care of?

*IIRC, the Ramban has a *kuntres* where he discussed this idea, but I don't know where it is.

Comment: https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%97/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90-%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%98%D7%90/

Comment: @Loewian can you perhaps elaborate as to what's in this link?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If Hashem said He'd protect Yaakov, and that was contingent on his merits, and Yaakov feared he lost those merits, where is the lack of bitachon?

Comment: In fact, isn't this why the Gemarra gives this explanation, and why Rashi brings this Midrash? The verse implies a lack of bitachon, and the answer is that's not the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Rambam in Chapter Seven of Shemoneh Perakim writes:

> It is not necessary for a prophet to have mastered all the ethical virtues to the point that he does not possess any shortcomings at all.
>
> (Touger translation p. 43)

He then provides various examples of prophets having shortcomings, the last of which is:

> And Jacob feared Esau.
>
> (Touger translation p. 44)